# How can I get all added categories which is added under page on the menu area in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

This is my website: http://futura-dev.totalcommit.com

Here you can see my first menu name and added sub pages under this menu.

```
1) Navegue por aqui! (custom link)  
   --- E AÍ, TÁ A FIM DE SABER SOBRE O QUE HOJE? (custom link)
   --- EDUCAÇÃO (page)
   --- CIDADANIA (page)
   --- BEM ESTAR E AMBIENTE (page)
   --- CULTURA (page)
   --- DINHEIRO (page)
   --- CIÊNCIAS E TECNOLOGIA(page)
```

After that, I have added few categories to each page which you can see on the site link.

Now I want to get all added categories from each page. is it possible in WordPress? If so, how can I do this?

**For example:** In this **CULTURA** page I have these categories: **Arte, Musica, Festas, Folclore**

I want to get these categoires.

[image]

Comment: There'a a pretty good video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beYiFTaJyiI)